# Why do questions display "-1 votes" instead of "-1 vote"?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, plurals

When a question has a score of -1, it displays "-1 votes" instead of "-1 vote". Is this a bug?

[image: Screenshot 1]

How about replacing "vote" and "votes" with "score" instead?

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: I regard that as a bug, and I tagged it as such. I never even noticed that before. But really though, calling the score "votes" is wrong too. A score represents the sum value of up and downvotes. You could have multiple votes on a post, yet have the score even out to 1 or -1. It shouldn't say votes at all.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694

Comment: @Mat there's no way Jeff is coming all the way out to my house, I live on the other side of the country `:P`

Comment: Watch out for Jeff coming with his giant S.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/is-1-singular-or-plural

Comment: A giant S. to kill a small bug? lol

Comment: I say we just change the word to "score" and be done with it. Honestly, "-1 votes" doesn't really make any sense. Seeing a -1 would imply there's at least one *vote*, causing a post *score* of -1. You can't have a negative number of votes.

Comment: @animuson, I would suggest *tally* instead of *score* to avoid too much gamification, though.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi we already crossed that line on day 1 `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake, true, but to me *score* makes it sound... a little unprofessional, for lack of a better term. As if we had *EXP* instead of *reputation*, for instance.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://pn.ispirt.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Tally-logo-Center.png)

Comment: But "tally" actually sounds a bit old-fashioned :P

Comment: @Murplyx, yup, I learned English last millennium ;)

Comment: What if we use "points" instead of score? Reddit uses points for comments, and Hacker News uses points for posts.

Comment: @Cupcake, same problem about `point` and `points` we're discussing in the first place.

Comment: It is *[an official meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791)*.

Comment: @Murplyx I don't think you should accept my answer, you should accept an answer from official staff on bug reports.

Comment: Many Stack Overlowians see @Jeff's [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/173052) as the answer to all questions about *pluralization* and judge questions about this as a *duplicate* since Stack Exchange sites have this as a **feature**, not as a *bug* (:

Answer (score 13):

### The Problem

I think calling a question's score "votes" is entirely misleading to begin with, whether it's pluralized or not, as discussed in the comments. A post can have 5 upvotes and 4 downvotes, for a total of 9 votes, and so displaying "1 vote" is just incorrect.

It makes even less sense when you display negative votes. The total number of votes on a post can only ever be non-negative, so displaying "-1 votes" or "-10 votes" just doesn't make sense.

### A Solution

We can either change it to say "score",

[image: Screenshot 1]

Or "points", as Reddit and Hacker News does:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Reddit comment:

[image: Reddit comment]

Hacker News submissions:

[image]

Of course, the problem with using "points" instead of "score" is that you still have to pluralize "points", while with "score", you do not.

Answer (score 7):

I guess we'll just [carry on the tradition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/163250) then:

> > ## Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant S

— [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/163250)

Comment: What hahahahappppeeeenddd tttto ttthe llassst ppeerson? No but seriously good luck on the airport :P

Comment: "But not you. I like you. You're nice." :D

Comment: http://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/5//3970/3970473_sprite198.swf

Comment: @Murplyx um, that link doesn't have viruses or anything, does it?

Comment: No just a fun whale.

Comment: Install security cameras, sacrifice your life, and then implicate him for murder. He'll get ruled guilty and will be put to death the same way (or some other method, or just put in jail without parole), and this will allow others to freely report such bugs.